Contar nodos de un arbol n-ario
Para contar nodos en un arbol n-ario, conviene hacerlo solo usando recursividad o con la estructura while? Entiendo que en terminos de eficiencia es preferente usar while+recursividad, pero no se que es lo que se suele hacer en este caso. Si tienen el código para este ejercicio sería de gran ayuda.

Tu pregunta está comparando 2 situaciones abstractas, es del tipo "quien corre más rápido: un perro o un gato", bueno, dependerá del perro y del gato en particular. Aquí lo mismo, en tu pregunta debes agregar la implementación de los 2 algoritmos que estas comparando e indicar el lenguaje usado. También tienes que definir a que te refieres con eficiencia, tiempo? memoria? orden de complejidad? otro?

Se me hace difícil pensar una solución solo recursiva o solo con whiles. Es possible que no haya entendido bien la pregunta. Falta ver cómo se implementa ese árbol n-ario para hablar de eficiencia.

la solucion recursiva es un poco mas simple porque no vas a necesitar tener una pila o cola aparte ya que la recursión va a darte la pila que necesitas.
Pero con iteración podrías optimizarlo más en términos de uso de memoria.
